# How to fix error in action listener in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

So I am having an error in my code which is I don't know why it happens cause I followed the instructions of my teacher. Whenever I add the parameter in the `addActionListener` I get this error.

This is my whole code

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DateFrameButton  implements ActionListener{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int FIELD_WIDTH = 20;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton dateButton = new JButton("Date");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        String dateAndTime = new Date(FIELD_WIDTH).toString();
        
        
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                textField.setText(dateAndTime);
            }
        };
        
        dateButton.addActionListener(listener);
        
        frame.add(dateButton);
        frame.add(textField);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

This is where I get the error:

```
dateButton.addActionListener(listener);
```

The error says

```
The method addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (ActionListener)
```

And I really don't know why it gets that error

Comment: Your class implements `ActionListener`.  You also instantiate a new `ActionListener` in the main method and add it to the button.

You should not do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                textField.setText(dateAndTime);
            }
         });
```

The button is confused about the argument passed. Is it the ActionListener class you implement? The instance created? It expects a `java.awt.event.ActionListener,` but it receives an `ActionListener`.

Do not create an instance of ActionListener, just make sure a `java.awt.event.ActionListener` is passed.